# Did every Marvel Universe title reset numbering after Secret Wars?

Tags: marvel, secret-wars

When *Secret Wars* hit, the 616 universe was destroyed, while that event took sometime to resolve, a **All-New, All-Different** universe was launched.
<sub>(Which [may or may not](http://ca.ign.com/articles/2015/06/23/spider-gwen-will-make-her-video-game-debut-this-fall) still be reffered to as 616)</sub>

Some relatively new books such as *All-New Hawkeye*, and *Uncanny Avengers v2* only made it to #5, before being relaunched post-Secret Wars into the All-New, All-Different universe with a new #1.

Did any Marvel Universe title retain numbering after entering the post-Secret Wars continuity?
<sub>So, excluding things like *Miracleman*, *Star Wars*, *The Dark Tower* etc...</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to say, as Secret Wars hasn't finished yet, and any titles left may very well end up not lasting longer than Secret Wars.

But **Groot** is seemingly set in the main marvel comic universe, wasn't part of Secret Wars, and so far hasn't been rebooted with a new number #1.

Comment: S.H.I.E.L.D. at least finished with #12, relaunching as Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. I believe Groot was the replacement for Rocket Racoon. What evidence do you have that Groot was initially set pre Secret Wars and contains post Secret Wars elements?

Comment: @NikolaiDante It started before the launch of the All New All Different and it wasn't part of secret wars (it takes place in space). As I stated in my answer it may end up being rebooted as well, but I don't think it has yet.